# GoCardless - Tokens

Tags: php, api, gocardless

I want to setup a  GoCardless sandbox. I have already signed up and I could log in. To connect I need account details (app_id, app_secret, merchant_id, access_token).

I am a bit confused where to find them from the Sandbox.

I went to "Developer" menu, but still could not get them.

Please help me. Am I walking along a wrong path?

I am following this:
https://developer.gocardless.com/legacy/php/#getting-the-library

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a legacy api, I think this not supported anymore, just the:
 https://github.com/fhferreira/gocardless-pro-php

and

https://developer.gocardless.com

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the legacy API is not recommended for new integrations. We recommend instead that you use https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-pro-php. You can create an Access Token by logging into your dashboard, going to https://manage.gocardless.com/developers, logging in, selecting "Create" on the top-right, and picking "Access Token".

You can find directions for getting started using GoCardless with PHP at https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/adding-your-first-customer/?lang=php